# Random Rails 3 erb partials taking very long time to render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm running Rails 3 and Ruby 1.8.7. I'm seeing this in my production logs constantly and it happens at random too. One of the partials in a loop of them being rendered taking an inordinate amount of time.

Rendered entries/_entry.html.erb (5.9ms)
Rendered entries/_entry.html.erb (7.9ms)
Rendered entries/_entry.html.erb (6.1ms)
Rendered entries/_entry.html.erb (1726.9ms)
Rendered entries/_entry.html.erb (5.2ms)
Rendered entries/_entry.html.erb (5.3ms)
Rendered entries/_entry.html.erb (5.3ms)
Rendered entries/_entry.html.erb (5.9ms)
Rendered entries/_entry.html.erb (5.4ms)

Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: I suspect it's not the partial rendering that is taking the time. Typically loading time is directly proportional to ActiveRecord. I bet you are running a weird query that is taking long. Post you whole log from the start of the request AND it would be helpful if we knew WHAT was in the partial...

Comment: I agree with @seth.vargo. May I also recommend running ruby-prof (in development) or NewRelic RPM (in production) to find the source of the slowdown.

Comment: At the end of a request the time spent in ActiveRecord is tiny compared to the time spent rendering. E.g.: Completed 200 OK in 9898ms (Views: 6030.5ms | ActiveRecord: 515.4ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms) <= This just started happening, never seen anything like it.

Comment: I wrapped the entire partial in an <% if false %> and it's still happening. It's a random one each time.

Comment: Try using `render :collection => @entries`.

Comment: I've been having the same issue lately too.

Answer (score 3):

One big slow render amidst small ones one like that is a sign that your **garbage collection** is happening then.  Switch to Rails enterprise Edition to solve it.  I also think ruby 1.9.2+ handles this better, though I'm not certain.